# Is "use" a noun in "the need for use unsupervised overseas"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, parts-of-speech, parsing

> Furthermore, the need for secrecy was tempered not only by the need for **use unsupervised overseas** but by the desire to use maps and charts to legitimate territorial claims, a function they could not logically provide without being public. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=7vOTAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA32&dq=furthermore%20the%20need%20for%20secrecy%20was%20tempered%20not%20only%20by%20the%20need%20for%20use%20unsupervised%20overseas&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM2cbil_XeAhWMvlMKHVQICTMQ6AEIKjAA))

I am not sure I am parsing that part of the sentence correctly. Is "use" a noun? It seems "the need for" calls for a noun, but then what is the role of "unsupervised overseas"? Since "unsupervised" is an adjective, "overseas" either an adjective or an adverb, isn't the structure *noun + adj + adv/adj*? I am hesitant to say this is a case of postpositive modification. What is it?

Shouldn't that part be *"need for unsupervised use overseas"*? Is *"need for use unsupervised overseas"* not a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, **use** seems to be a noun there, modified by the clause *unsupervised overseas*. So it could be rewritten:

... need for unsupervised use overseas

or even

... need for unsupervised overseas use

**unsupervised** is an adjectival modifier formed from the negated past participle of the verb **supervise**.

Comment: I think I also meant to ask "shouldn't that part be _'need for unsupervised use overseas'_?" And "is _'need for use unsupervised overseas'_ not a mistake?"

Comment: It is not a mistake. It seems a stylistic decision to emphasize the fact that  the use would be unsupervised overseas.  If you cannot supervise the use from a distance, you cannot control the secret.